# Differences between jar and war in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, war

I'm about to build my first website in Java with Spring Framework using Spring Boot and it's much easier to build it in `jar`, but I have a few questions about it.

What are the differences in general?

In `jar` files the views are under `/resources/templates`, but in `war` file it's under `/webapp/WEB-INF/`.

What are the differences? Can I deploy a `jar` on an online host?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Spring Boot can be told to produce a 'fat JAR' which includes all of your module/service's dependencies and can be run with [`java -jar <your jar>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html). See "Create an executable JAR with Maven" [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html).

Spring Boot can also be told to [produce a WAR file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html), in which case you'll likely choose to deploy it to a web container such as Tomcat or Jetty.

Plenty more details on Spring Boot deployment [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications).

Comment: and don't forget to exclude the embedded tomcat in this case; check the link in @lazyneuron's answer

Comment: @HamaSaadwn just fyi, spring-boot application build as `war` could also be run as `java -jar xxx.war`. It could be used in some transition phase when you're making changes to your deployment infrastructure with moving to `fat jar`

Comment: Whether it's "fat" (i.e. containing all dependencies) and executable or not, does not depend on whether it's a .jar or .war file.  This currently accepted answer does not explain the difference between both (which is what was asked).

Comment: What is the difference? You didn't answer the question!!!

Comment: the real question was never answered? I thought the original question was about the difference...

Answer (score 26):

Depends on your deployment. If you are planning to deploy your application to an existing Java EE Application Server (e.g. Tomcat), then standard approach is to perform a `war` build.

When you use fat jar approach, your application will be deployed on embedded application container provided by spring boot. Conduct [Deploying Spring Boot Applications](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) for more information.

Comment: This is the proper answer (stating the difference) to the question amongst all.

Comment: You can create an executable war file as well, in which case it works the same as a jar but with a war layout.  So this isn't really the difference between both.

Comment: why a person will choose to deploy on an external server ? is not that means loosing on the beauty of sprint boot which was suppose to have auto initializing the server..

Answer (score 15):

### Running `spring-boot` application as fat `*.jar`

It is possible to build so called `fat JAR` that is executable `*.jar` file with embedded application container (`Tomcat` as default option).
There are `spring-boot` plugins for various build systems. Here is the one for `maven`: [spring-boot-maven-plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/)

To execute the kind of `fat` `*.jar` you could simple run command:

```
java -jar *.jar
```

Or using `spring-boot-maven` goal:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

### Building `spring-boot` application as `*.war` archive

The other option is to ship your application as old-fashioned `war` file. It could be deployed to any servlet container out there. Here is step by step how-to list:

1. Change `packaging` to `war` (talking about maven's `pom.xml`)
2. Inherit main `spring-boot` application class from `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override `SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder)` method (see [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html))
3. Make sure to set the `scope` of `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as `provided`

[More info in spring-boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging)

Comment: do the same steps apply to gradle?

Comment: @HamaSaadwn absolutely!

Comment: Thank you, but in case of fat jar, how we can configure tomcat? for example configure ssl?

Comment: @ashkanr see the list of spring-boot properties here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html. 
Basically, properties are the common way to configure embedded Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 6):

I was under the same problem, when I deployed my jar issue free on my local. Then I had to demo it on the server. You can create a war file by changing the pom.xml , tag

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

to

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and you will have a war file in your target which you can deploy to your server(tomcat in my case)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to deploy it in an external container, you'll normally have to create a war file (which doesn't have to be executable).

If you want to use the embedded container, you can choose to create an executable .jar file or an executable .war file.  AFAIK the only difference is in the layout of the archive, and therefore normally also the layout of your source repository.

E.g. using standard folder structure with Maven / Gradle, static resources for a .jar will need to be in `src/main/resources/static` while for a .war file they should be in `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: ... while for a **.war** file they should be in `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: @HolmesQueen good catch, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

`war` file is a **Web Application Archive** which runs inside an application server while a `.jar` is **Java Application Archive** that runs a desktop application on a user's machine. A war file is a special jar file that is used to package a web application to make it easy to deploy it on an application server.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and easy answer.
Packaging type `jar` represented as standalone application and packaging type `war` represented as web application.